# Show date in UTC in ASP:GridView BoundField

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datagridview, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm trying to use a `GridView` to show a `DateTime` value.  So far I have been able to show the data using the format string that I want by using:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" ... >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField" DataFormatString={0:MM/dd/yyyy hhmmss} ... />
        ...
    </Columns>
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

The problem I'm having now is that this is always being shown as local time.  My users will be expecting it to always be shown as UTC, regardless of where they are.  **Is there some way I can force the `GridView` to show what the UTC time would be, instead of the local time?**

For example, I have found out that in vb.net, to convert a string to a date I can tell it to use universal time with:

```
Dim myDateAsString as String = "03/31/2014 19:00"
Dim myDate as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateAsString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
```

I'm looking for something similar to the `.AssumeUniversal` part that I can use when I set up my `GridView` in asp.

I hope what I'm asking is clear.  If not I can try to elaborate more, if someone let's me know what isn't clear.

---

UPDATE:

The `DataSource` for my `GridView` is a `DataSet` that is filled by a `SELECT` query that just pulls data from my database.  Since the field I'm interested in here is a `DateTime` field in my database, I am assuming it will still be a `DateTime` when it gets assigned as the `DataSource`.  Is that correct?

It looks to me like the only code related to filling the `GridView` is

```
myGrid.DatqaSource = mySQLObject.sel_from_table(vars)
myGrid.DataBind()
```

Where `mySQLObject.sel_from_table(vars)` will return a `DataSet` as described above.  The answers so far have suggested that I need to change the data to UTC before sending it to the `GridView` - Where/how should that be done?  Do I have to change it in my query somehow?  Or in the `DataSet` before I assign it as the `DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid view is merely a display mechanism. It'll display whatever value you pass it in the format you specified. If you want to change the value itself (Utc Date) then 2 options are:

1. Template Item where you can call an Eval option to compute Utc Date.
2. Change the value of myField server side so that the grid view can bind that. e.g. in your SQL query results.

Either ways, your server side code needs to convert the date into UTC (ToUniversalTime() or DateTime.UtcNow etc.) and send it across for display.

here is how you can do using TemplateField.

in your ASPX

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Fields">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" text='<%# GetUtcFormattedDate((DateTime)Eval("myField")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your code behind, you can have a static method

```
public static string GetUtcFormattedDate(DateTime date)
{
 return date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(YOUR_DATE_FORMAT_STRING);
}
```

Comment: Hm, ok.  If my `DataSource` is just the results of a `SELECT` query, how would I do the conversion before it gets to the `GridView`?  See the update to my OP.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm actually using vb, so I had to play with what you had a little, but the `TemplateField` with `Eval` idea worked beautifully.

Comment: Glad. In future if you want vb from c#, there are online conversion sites. Paste c#, get vb.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the time to UTC in your query to pull the data from the database.

In your select clause just use the below.

```
SELECT DATEADD (HH, 'Your UTC Offset', DateYouWantSelected)
```

Comment: Due to Daylight savings, the UTC offset might not be constant, so I don't think doing it this way will work for me.

Comment: You can pass in the UTC offset from the application that you are running.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset.aspx

Comment: From the link you provided: `NOTE:The GetUtcOffset method recognizes only the current daylight saving time adjustment rule for the local time zone. As a result, it is guaranteed to accurately return the UTC offset of a local time only during the period in which the latest adjustment rule is in effect. It may return inaccurate results if time is a historic date and time value that was subject to a previous adjustment rule.`  Using `DATEADD` only works when the offset will always be the same.  That won't be the case for me.